# Prove $\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} e^{-x^T M x}\;dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi^n}{\det M}}.$

Tags: integration

I have read that if $M$ is $n$ by $n$ and positive definite (which also implies symmetric) then 
$$\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} e^{-x^T M x}\;dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi^n}{\det M}}.$$

How can one prove this?

Comment: Making the change of variables (orthogonal transformation) that brings $M$ to diagonal form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $M$ is symmetric positive definite, we have $M=LL^T$ for some $L$ (Cholesky, for instance). Hence, setting $y=Lx$, we obtain $dy = \det(L)dx$. Hence, the integral becomes,
$$\int_{y \in \mathbb{R}^n} e^{-y^Ty} \dfrac{dy}{\det(L)} = \dfrac{\left(\int_{y \in \mathbb{R}} e^{-y^2}dy\right)^n}{\det(L)} = \dfrac{\left(\sqrt{\pi}\right)^n}{\sqrt{\det(M)}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi^n}{\det(M)}}$$

Comment: I think you can also diagonalize and then use the diagonalization to extract a proper square root. Then you need to use the orthogonality, though.